# Custom UINavigationBar Image

Tags: objective-c, ios

I am trying to implement a custom UINavigationBar Image background for iOS 6 but I am having no luck. All it displays is the normal one from Apple (with no back button). 
I have tried the following code within viewDidLoad (One at time):

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:myImage forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:myImage forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

I am presenting the desired view by:

```
optionViewController *choose= [[optionViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"optionViewController" bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *aNavController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:choose];
[self presentViewController: aNavController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What happen? [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"barImage.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarStyleDefault]; This command work everywhere in my code, both for iOS5 and iOS6.

Comment: @LêQuýSang Nothing happens... It simply displays the typical basic UINaviationBar and not the image I want. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can set Navigation bar Custom image like this way:-

```
        optionViewController *choose= [[optionViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"optionViewController" bundle:nil];
        UINavigationController *aNavController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:choose];
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"imageName"];
        [aNavController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:image forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

        [self presentModalViewController:aNavController animated:YES]; //change here to PresentViewcontroller to presentmodelViewcontroller
```

here' is image:-

[image]

and in above image the `Back` button is not the Default one, but it's putting through programmatically.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but if you look above I have already tried that. Any other suggestions? Thanks

Comment: you tryong but you not trying with this line UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"navBarLoc.png"]; just trying this

Comment: Ahh sorry I assumed that was understood... I have that line of code in my actually project. Thanks

Comment: check now and implement it

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22041/discussion-between-nitin-gohel-and-alex-g)

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
if([self.navigationController.navigationBar respondsToSelector:@selector(setBackgroundImage:forBarMetrics:)] ) {
    //iOS 5 new UINavigationBar custom background
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"navbg_ForiPhone5_Imagename.png"] forBarMetrics: UIBarMetricsDefault];
} else {
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar insertSubview:[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"navbg_ForOtherIphone_Imagename.png"]] atIndex:0];
}
```

and For info goto this [link](http://iphoneeasydevelopment.blogspot.com/search/label/General)